# In R / RStudio, find the row ID that contains a string from one column for each row of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

If a row has text with in the "ReferenceText" column within my dataframe, the corresponding text within the "Text" column represents a reply comment. If NA then the corresponding text in the "Text" column represents an original post.

If possible I'd like to use regular expressions (I'm thinking gregexpr and regmatches), but if there is another form of pattern matching to do the following in R / RStudio:

I'd like to find the "ReferenceText" text's matching text within the "Text" column and place the corresponding  the "ID" of the "Text" observation in my "PostID" column  for each "ReferenceText" observation.  I'd also like to index the order ("Sequence") of each reply comment's "PostID".

For example, if an original Post (PostID=5) is replied to ("Text" text found in the "ReferenceText" row 6 row 9), "ReferenceText" row 6 "PostID" observation will be labeled as "PostID=5", the "Sequence" observation will be labelled as "PostID=5 Sequence=1". If the original post is replied to again or repeated in "ReferenceText" ("ReferenceText" row 9), then that "Sequence" observation would be labeled as "PostID=5 Sequence=2".  I have quite a large data set (160,000+ observations) and so a function that can answer this problem would be greatly appreciated. Any ideas?

I hope that makes sense.   NOTE that ANY R / RStudio solution will suffice. 
[image: image of my sampleDF]

I am pasting the dput output of my data.frame object.

```
## dput output assigned to my sampleDF data frame
> dput(sampleDF)
structure(list(ID = 1:30, Screen.Name = c("User 1", "User 2", 
"User 3", "User 4", "User 5", "User 6", "User 7", "User 8", "User 5", 
"User 9", "User 9", "User 1", "User 1", "User 10", "User 8", 
"User 11", "Company", "User 12", "User 13", "User 14", "User 15", 
"User 16", "User 17", "User 18", "User 19", "User 13", "User 20", 
"User 21", "Uer 21", "User 21"), Text = c("Can anyone tell me where in the bloody world this TROLL came from.  Is he the troll of the week at the national trolling academy?  https://www.facebook.com/joseph.barnhorst", 
"company's \"You're Kinda a Big Deal\" promotion is kinda lame and insulting.  How about a service that actually is up to speed as advertised?  Now THATwould be a big deal for company.", 
"Hope I win sumthing!", "Im paying 90 dollars for a reason, so fix whatever is broken so I can actually use my phone!", 
"How do you sign up for the Your A Big Deal Sweepstakes?", "http://company.promo.eprize.com/sweepstakes/:b=chrome/?INTCID=TSC:MyS:MyA:Skn:013113:EngagementSweeps#", 
"Thanks for your giant mess up. I'm down 370 dollars.", "When will the blackberry 10 be available ?", 
"Thank you for the link but should the email get you there also?  I clicked on the mobile ad in and e-bill options to finish the sign up for those and received an error message for both.  Perhaps a link isn't working properly there either.", 
"Wait, Could it be Joseph is upset cause his Milkshake didn't bring the boys to his yard? Must see, look at this > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFK8zYYoMtQ", 
"What a putz.... lol", "LMBO!", "The Blackberry Q10 will be available to US carriers in April.", 
"My mobile hot spot just shut off Randomly and now It tell me to set it up again I already have it on my plan", 
"I'm really interested in seeing this phone, I hope it's as good if not better than iPhones cause nothing new has challenged apple really", 
"Turn off the LTE in Carlisle it does work like at all. Or please fix. Won't load anything under LTE", 
"Need a hand? Check out this redesigned umbrella handle that lets you keep texting even during a downpour. http://bit.ly/12fniVl", 
"why we are still having service issues,  ", "unlimited data isn't worth anything when you can't get service with or without a femtocell and tech support has been next to useless over the past few months.", 
"Because everyone should be texting while walking in the rain... face palm.", 
"When is the LTE going to be available in NYC?? I was told end of last year... but it's Feb now.....", 
"Get us 4g already", "So silly. But people will buy it I am sure", 
"rubbish", "Free umbrella with company phones?! I bet it helps with the sewage internet connection you guys have.", 
"oh and more loveliness.. just had a company rep hang up on me..this is twice...nice job.", 
"Oh wow", "The pressure is getting to them. The CEO has put them in a no win situation.", 
"Never", "LTE means Lying To Everyone."), ReferenceText = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "How do you sign up for the Your A Big Deal Sweepstakes?", 
"NA", "NA", "How do you sign up for the Your A Big Deal Sweepstakes?", 
"Can anyone tell me where in the bloody world this TROLL came from.  Is he the troll of the week at the national trolling academy?  https://www.facebook.com/joseph", 
"Can anyone tell me where in the bloody world this TROLL came from.  Is he the troll of the week at the national trolling academy?  https://www.facebook.com/joseph", 
"Can anyone tell me where in the bloody world this TROLL came from.  Is he the troll of the week at the national trolling academy?  https://www.facebook.com/joseph", 
"When will the blackberry 10 be available ?", "NA", "When will the blackberry 10 be available ?", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Need a hand? Check out this redesigned umbrella handle that lets you keep texting even during a downpour. http://bit.ly/12fniVl", 
"NA", "Need a hand? Check out this redesigned umbrella handle that lets you keep texting even during a downpour. http://bit.ly/12fniVl", 
"Need a hand? Check out this redesigned umbrella handle that lets you keep texting even during a downpour. http://bit.ly/12fniVl", 
"Need a hand? Check out this redesigned umbrella handle that lets you keep texting even during a downpour. http://bit.ly/12fniVl", 
"Need a hand? Check out this redesigned umbrella handle that lets you keep texting even during a downpour. http://bit.ly/12fniVl", 
"NA", "Need a hand? Check out this redesigned umbrella handle that lets you keep texting even during a downpour. http://bit.ly/12fniVl", 
"oh and more loveliness.. just had a company rep hang up on me..this is twice...nice job. ", 
"When is the LTE going to be available in NYC?? I was told end of last year... but it's Feb now.....", 
"NA"), PostID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Sequence = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DATE = c("2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", 
"2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", 
"2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", 
"2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", 
"2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", 
"2/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2013"), X_M__millitary_time_ = c("16:46:20", 
"16:52:07", "16:55:54", "17:08:41", "17:10:08", "17:13:01", "17:13:17", 
"17:15:17", "17:19:01", "17:36:39", "17:41:08", "17:42:44", "17:45:42", 
"17:50:08", "17:50:53", "17:53:25", "18:00:01", "18:01:18", "18:03:37", 
"18:04:26", "18:05:41", "18:10:58", "18:11:17", "18:11:20", "18:11:41", 
"18:11:58", "18:13:19", "18:17:13", "18:18:34", "18:19:53"), 
timestampM = c("2/1/2013 16:46", "2/1/2013 16:52", "2/1/2013 16:55", 
"2/1/2013 17:08", "2/1/2013 17:10", "2/1/2013 17:13", "2/1/2013 17:13", 
"2/1/2013 17:15", "2/1/2013 17:19", "2/1/2013 17:36", "2/1/2013 17:41", 
"2/1/2013 17:42", "2/1/2013 17:45", "2/1/2013 17:50", "2/1/2013 17:50", 
"2/1/2013 17:53", "2/1/2013 18:00", "2/1/2013 18:01", "2/1/2013 18:03", 
"2/1/2013 18:04", "2/1/2013 18:05", "2/1/2013 18:10", "2/1/2013 18:11", 
"2/1/2013 18:11", "2/1/2013 18:11", "2/1/2013 18:11", "2/1/2013 18:13", 
"2/1/2013 18:17", "2/1/2013 18:18", "2/1/2013 18:19"), timestampN = c("2/1/2013 16:46", 
"2/1/2013 16:52", "2/1/2013 16:55", "2/1/2013 17:08", "2/1/2013 17:10", 
"2/1/2013 17:13", "2/1/2013 17:13", "2/1/2013 17:15", "2/1/2013 17:19", 
"2/1/2013 17:36", "2/1/2013 17:41", "2/1/2013 17:42", "2/1/2013 17:45", 
"2/1/2013 17:50", "2/1/2013 17:50", "2/1/2013 17:53", "2/1/2013 18:00", 
"2/1/2013 18:01", "2/1/2013 18:03", "2/1/2013 18:04", "2/1/2013 18:05", 
"2/1/2013 18:10", "2/1/2013 18:11", "2/1/2013 18:11", "2/1/2013 18:11", 
"2/1/2013 18:11", "2/1/2013 18:13", "2/1/2013 18:17", "2/1/2013 18:18", 
"2/1/2013 18:19")), .Names = c("ID", "Screen.Name", "Text", 
"ReferenceText", "PostID", "Sequence", "DATE", "X_M__millitary_time_", 
"timestampM", "timestampN"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: I see you have the regex tag and the r tag. Some of the best regex people on the planet come here, but don't know a thing about 'r'. If you need a solution using regex, you might want to translate the 'r' speak to something simpler. If you don't need regex, please take it's tag off.

Comment: `sampleDF$PostID <- match(sampleDF$ReferenceText,sampleDF$Text, incomparables=NA)` Was the solution to the first half of my problem. I'm trying to figure out how to yeild the sequence via `findInterval`